# Create Interface for WCF Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have recently started working with WCF design, to send messages securely from a web page to an application.

So far, I have successfully created a WCF Library that runs, and a web page the currently links to the service, sends a message, and receives the reply.

Unfortunately, due to my very new approach to it, and somewhat outdated tutorials I have read, I don't know correctly how to (or don't know the correct way) to add a server side interface to this Library (if possible) so I can see some output on what the server is doing.

Could anyone show me how to correctly add an interface to allow me to see?

In `ObfuscationService`

```
public class ObfuscationService : IObfuscation
    {
        public string Message(string msg)
        {
            return "Your message is: " + msg;
        }
    }
```

On the web app:

```
private void ServerService()
    {
        ObfuscationClient obfuClient = new ObfuscationClient();
        Response.Write(obfuClient.Message(@txtInput.Text));
    }
```

All I am doing for now is sending a message and returning it.

I need to elaborate methods on the string though, and I need UI on the server so I can print the process on the screen, show how many users are connected etc.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, possibly by adding more details/code so that we can help you

Comment: Updated, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Isnt IObfuscation is your interface?

Comment: Seems you already had an interface

Comment: It isnt a visual thing. A test interface comes up, but outside of the VS environment, I cant run it like an .exe (I dont want to sound noobish - but thats the only way I can say it)

Comment: I may be wrong- may be you need to create a new application to call methods or if you just want to test the result you can use WcfTestClient (opened from Visual Studio Command Propmpt) to run/test the methods you created.

Comment: It does. as I said, the test client runs perfectly. But I need to know how to make a production client to run on my server.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments

See this link:

[wcftestclient fails, but only on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982990/wcftestclient-fails-but-only-on-remote-machine)

You might need to write complete IP address

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, moons. I just need to know how to create the interface for the library. Right now, it compiles to a .dll. I need to make a windows app that will act as the viewing part of the dll.

Comment: @NewAmbition May be you can host WCF in windows service. Try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx